# Using curl in ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

Could someone tell me the equivalent code to use it in ruby?

```
 curl --cert cert_file --key key_file -H "x-amzn-iot-thingname: cn_name"  --cacert AmazonRootCA1.pem https://endpoint/role-aliases/role_alias/credentials
```

[UPDATE]

```
  uri = URI("https://endpoint/role-aliases/role_alias/credentials")
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  req["x-amzn-iot-thingname"] = "cn_name"
  req_options = {
     use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
     ca_file: "/path-to-file/RootCA.pem", 
     #cert: "/path-to-file/mycert.crt",
     #key: "/path-to-file/mykey.key",
     cert: OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/path-to-file/mycert.crt")),
     key: OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/path-to-file/mykey.key")),
  }
 res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port,req_options) do |http|
     http.request(req)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://endpoint/role-aliases/role_alias/credentials")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["X-Amzn-Iot-Thingname"] = "cn_name"

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# response.code
# response.body
```

Thanks to the first line in https://duckduckgo.com response: https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/

Comment: At the moment I get a connection timeout error. The curl command is working as expected. Is there anything wrong in my setup using key, cert and ca_file? I tried to use the paths to the files and after that the current solution

Comment: At first glance everything looks fine. Connection timeout means the issue is not with _SSL_, if it was _SSL_, it would fail immediately.